# Setting the map as hybrid has no effect?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mapkit

Does anyone know why setting the map as hybrid has no effect.  Setting it as standard and satellite works fine though?

.
.
.

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSegmentClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)handleSegmentClick:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"changeSegment");

    UISegmentedControl *sc = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

    NSInteger index = sc.selectedSegmentIndex;

    switch (index) 
    {
        case 0:
            [mapView setMapType: MKMapTypeStandard];
            break;
        case 1:
            [mapView setMapType: MKMapTypeSatellite];
            break;
        case 2:
            [mapView setMapType: MKMapTypeHybrid];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also the same problem. I think it has to do with the location - not all areas are supported for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and works for me. Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else? Are you setting the map type again somewhere?

Comment: No, I am running it through the simulator though, could that be the reason?  It switches to standardview and everything. Let me add the rest of the code

Comment: Put some log statements into your switch statement to see if the hybrid case is actually getting called. That might give a clue to what's happening. Try changing the first case to hybrid.

Comment: Yep the hybrid is actually being called

Comment: WHat I mean is that its still not working - its definitely being called but has no affect even running on the device

Answer (score 0):

You didn't connect the Outlets in Interface Builder.